# поиск по паттерну

Tags: javascript

```js
function countBs(str) {
    let result = str.match( /b/gi );
    return result
}

let a = "pobeda pobeda vmesto obeda"
console.log( countBs(a) )
```

Выводит `[b,b,b]`,но как `result` сделать числом?
Проще говоря нужно что-бы получилось кол-во букв `b`

Comment: например `.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> return result
> ```

```
return result ? result.length : 0
```

Comment: А для чего вопросительный знак?

Comment: @Australia, для случая, когда в строке нет буквы `b`, в этом случае `result` будет `null`

Comment: @Grundy, Аа,я понял )

Answer (score 0):

`match()` ищет совпадения и возвращает массив... через length можно посчитать колчество элементов этого массива. Но если совпадений не будет и ничего не вернет - будет ошибка, Поэтому рядом добавлен ИЛИ пустой массив `|| []` — в случае ноль совпадений, посчитает кол-во элементов пустого массива, = 0.

```js
function countBs(str) {
  return ( str.match( /b/gi ) || [] ).length;
}

let a = "pobeda pobeda vmesto obeda"

console.log( countBs(a) );
```

Можно сделать более универсальный сочик:

```js
function count(str, pattern) {
  let reg = new RegExp( pattern, "gi" );
  return ( str.match( reg ) || [] ).length;
}

let a = "pobeda pobeda vmesto obeda"

console.log( count(a, 'a') );
console.log( count(a, 'po') );
console.log( count(a, 'bubu') );
```